# When using file uploads, selected file does not clear in Angular with PrimeNG

Tags: angular, file-upload, upload, primeng

I am new to programming and I am facing the following problem. I need to upload multiple files with extensions ".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx,.rar,.webp" for this I have created a modal for the upload using PrimeNg's upload-file but When selecting the files, the selections are not cleaned. For example, I select the first file to upload, the file is succesfully added to my array but when I click the "X" for discard my  button again, I do not get the option to select a new file. Instead, the previous file I selected is added to the array again. And for that reason I have the following error **net::ERR_FAILED 413 (Payload Too Large)**

I have used this example from the PrimeNG documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v16-lts/fileupload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6pWe.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puhDb.png)

In addition, to load I must first convert the files into base64 and obtain a token.

The way I have been doing it is as follows. (this code is for small files).

For `component.ts`

```
uploadedFiles: any[] = [];
@ViewChild('fileUpload') fileUpload: any;

  getTokenUpload(user: string, ci: string) {
    let token = ''
    this.service.getToken(environment.SCOPES["carga"]).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        token = data.access_token
        this.onUploadWithToken(user, ci, token);
        this.clearFileUpload()
        // console.log(token)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error obteniendo datos: ', error);
      }
    );
  }


  onUploadWithToken(user: string, ci: string, token: string) {
    this.blockUI.start("Cargando...")
    this.service.uploadFiles(user, ci, this.base64DataArray, token).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.showUploadFiles = false
        this.base64DataArray = []
        this.blockUI.stop()
        this.showMessage('success', 'Éxito', 'Se ha realizado la carga de archivos con éxito')
        this.getToken()
        // console.log('Subido')
      },
      () => {
        console.log('error')
        this.showMessage('error', 'Error al cargar', 'No se ha podido realizar la carga de archivos')
        this.blockUI.stop()
      }
    )
    // this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Éxito', detail: 'Se han guardado los archivos con éxito'});
  }

onFileSelected(event: any): void {
    const files = event.files;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      this.convertToBase64Array(files);
    }
  }

  clearFileUpload(): void {
    if (this.fileUpload) {
      this.fileUpload.clear();
    }
  }

  convertToBase64Array(files: File[]): void {
    for (const file of files) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        let base64Data = e.target.result;
        base64Data = this.getBase64WithoutPrefix(base64Data)
        this.base64DataArray.push({ filename: file.name, file: base64Data });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  getBase64WithoutPrefix(base64Data: string): string {
    return base64Data.replace(/^data:[^;]+;base64,/, '');
  }
```

For `HMTL`

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="showUploadFiles" [style]="{width: '1050px'}" header="Selección de archivos"
          [modal]="true" styleClass="p-fluid" [resizable]="true">

  <p-fileUpload #fileUpload
                        name="files[]"
                        (onBeforeUpload)="getTokenUpload(user, ci)"
                        (onSelect)="onFileSelected($event)"
                        [multiple]="true"
                        accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx,.rar,.webp"
                        maxFileSize="187286400"
                        chooseLabel="Seleccionar" uploadLabel="Cargar" cancelLabel="Cancelar">

            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
              <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{ file.name }} - {{ file.size }} bytes</li>
              </ul>
            </ng-template>
  </p-fileUpload>
</p-dialog>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong but I do know that I need help optimizing the code.

**Versions:**

- Angular 15
- PrimeNG 16

I want to be able to optimize the code, load only the files displayed in the modal.

Comment: you probably shouldn't be converting to base64 client side.  I'd guess that's part of the issue.  It's usually best to just send a FormData object.  Server-side should do the base64 conversion if that's really necessary.  Remember that you'll be increasing the size of the payload whenever you base64 encode binary data.  Also, as is, I can only see files being added via event.files.  Can't tell where this.fileUpload is being used but you push files to base64DataArray based on event.files.